# Playing video on iPad in native app and webview

Tags: iphone, video, webview

I have a native iPad app that plays video. The app also uses a webview for some content and I would like to play a video in the webview as well.

Is it possible to play video natively as well as in a webview at the same time? I've read that only one video can play natively at the same time but does this apply if one video is native and the other is in a webview?

If a video is playing natively and a webview is loaded that includes a video, would initiating playback of the video in the webview automatically stop the native video or does there need to be communication from the webview to the native code to stop the video, and vice versa?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it isn't possible, in my experience when playing video in a webview the video is able to go fullscreen and when this happens it uses the same video player/controls that playing a video natively uses. I can't see how two videos would be able to use this player/controls at the same time.

You will also encounter memory issues, at least on the first iPad.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. so assuming simultaneous videos are out, if a video is playing natively, and the webview is loaded and a video is played within it would the native video stop automatically? My utlimate goal (which I realise may be a long shot) would be for the native video to stop when a video is played in the webview and more importantly for the playback of the video in the webview to take precedence over the native video. cont...

Comment: cont.. The video in the webview would be controlled via javascript and would be more of a sequence/animation that I would want to playout in full, and not stopped by the initiation of native video playback by the user. (I cannot currently make changes to the native source)